# Why do most of us love music?

Tags: music

Why do some of us enjoy music? And how did it even started in the first place? It somehow just appeared with us and stayed in most of our existence. We all can't escape music. It shows up on radios, movie theaters, televisions, commercials, etc. It's just there controlling our emotions. It soothes us or it gives us inspirations. It's quite mysterious...

Comment: This is a fascinating question that has nothing to do with building a world.

Comment: Well there is a possibility it relates to building a world. And besides that, there are other questions that don't even relate to building a world either. So I'm not the only one.

Comment: Can you link to these questions you think aren't related to worldbuilding. If they aren't closed they should be.

Comment: Normally it's a good idea to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer so that people from every timezone get a chance to weigh in.

Comment: "I don't stitch to the policy because others do not, too" is not a good approach. We have a policy of answering world building questions here.

Comment: This might be better migrated to [one](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/) of the [two](https://music.stackexchange.com/) music related sites.  Or perhaps [philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Lifeless Thunder*! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Your question seems to be off-topic for me, as it doesn't have anything to do with building an element of a world. It seems like a philosophical question about our current world without any intention of changing anything. Could you please [edit] it to explain how exactly this question relates to building a world? And please flag other questions you see that are off-topic so the community can close them. I amvoting to put this on hold for now. Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

*Some possibilities...*

`Physicists might answer:`
It's due to resonance of sound with the wave nature of the quantum particles within our being.   "Wave–particle duality is the concept in quantum mechanics that every particle or quantic entity may be partly described in terms not only of particles, but also of waves" (definition from Wikipedia).  Music includes many different waves of sound blended together.

Perhaps there are differences of the kinds of wave-particles we each are made of that makes us love different kinds of music, yet all love some version of it because it harmonizes with the "wave" in us. When one person perceives a certain kind of music as irritating and unpleasant, it may be because its wavelengths are dissonant, or or of sync with that person's own wavelength patterns. When a person loves many different kinds of music, they could be able to adjust their own internal "tuner" that allows them to harmonize with the music they are listening to, and adjust this as they choose.

`Biologists and behaviorists might answer:`

As young babies in the womb we begin life with the first most prominent sounds being that of the rhythmic rush of blood through our mothers arteries and veins, thumping along at a ceaseless and very reliable beat. This sets a precedence for all later learned sensory responses to other stimuli to be calmed and more easily assessed when accompanied by a steady beat and sounds working within a rhythm. Mothers naturally hum and sing to calm a fretful baby, which reinforces this even more. Eventually, as we learn about more and more stimuli (including sounds) and can connect and appreciate them in sophisticated ways, we love music, which is a more sophisticated version of that first beat and rhythm.

`Eddie van Halen might say:`
"Everybody's lookin' for somethin' 
Somethin' to fill in the holes"

Music is like love.... It fills the holes.

Then, "How does it feel when it's love
It's just something you feel together"

We all can feel music together.... which might also be the sociologists take on this question... It connects us to other people in a profound and inherently known way. Two people who have never met and who know nothing at all about each other can sit together and enjoy the same piece of music and feel an instant connection of "hey, this person is like me in this one small way...cool."  I don't know the word for that feeling so I just listed the thoughts that go with it.

Comment: Though your last paragraph really does not explain why what is music to some people can be horribly intrusive noise to others.

Comment: I'm very new at this and I know it only says to point out on parts you need to improve but I'd like to thank you for answering this question in details. That's all I wanted to say.